# borrar elementos de un array de dos en dos

Tags: javascript

Como hago para borrar elementos de un array de dos en dos

```
myArr = ['Keep', 'Remove', 'Keep', 'Remove', 'Keep', ...];

function removeEveryOther(arr){

arr.splice(1,3);
// No se como hacer la logica!

return arr;
}
```

Comment: Saludos. Ayudara expliques conforme lo que tienes lo que debe ser el resultado, el proceso que esperas se realice.

Comment: En realidad es un ejercicio ramdon, son una cantidad de numeros, y luego una cantidad de strings, se me ocurrio un for pero no se como plantearlo

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Si el proceso no lo tienes claro será imposible dar con lo que esperas, te comento si ya tienes un `array` con `n`elementos y quieres eliminar 2 elementos cualquiera; crea 2 variables y (a manera de ejemplo) `var posicion1 =Math.trunc(Math.random()*arr.length);` así obtienes 2 posiciones aleatorias a borrar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una buena opción es `splice()` dentro de un ciclo `for`:

```
function quitarde2en2(arr){
    for (let i = 0;i < arr.length;i = i + 1) {
        arr.splice(i + 1,1)
    }

    return arr
}
```

El ciclo for incrementa de uno en uno, pero `splice()` selecciona el siguiente elemento.

**Resultados:**

```
console.log(quitarde2en2(arr))
```

Con tu lista:

```
[ 'Keep', 'Keep', 'Keep' ]
```

Con una lista de los números del 0 al 9:

```
[ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

Espero haberte ayudado, más información sobre `splice()` [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice). Saludos. :)

Comment: Ahora si lo entiendo perfecto, gracias por tu explicacion. Saludos!!

Answer (score 2):

Podemos completar tu ejercicio de esta forma:

- La función recibe 2 argumentos que serán:

  - el vector original de valores
  - el vector que contendrá a la pareja de valores a encontrar y eliminar
- Dentro de la función evaluamos si el vector de elementos a eliminar tiene una longitud igual a 2, con eso verificamos que si contiene la cantidad de elementos que necesitamos remover, en caso negativo lo notificamos y en caso afirmativo retornamos los siguientes pasos del procedimiento (de esta forma evitamos una estructura regular `if/else`)
- A una variable que declararemos dentro del contexto de la función le asignamos el resultado de la iteración de los valores del vector original
- Para quitar a la pareja de elementos, usamos el método `filter`<sup>1</sup> donde indicaremos una doble condición para evaluar si los valores en pareja existen en el vector original indicando sus índices (*que para este caso serían 0 y 1*)
- Retornamos dentro del contexto de la función a la variable que contiene el vector filtrado, es decir al que le quitamos la pareja de valores deseados.

Consideramos el uso de dicho método<sup>1</sup> pues como indica en el enlace mencionado al final de esta respuesta:

> El método filter() crea un nuevo array con todos los elementos que cumplan la condición implementada por la función dada.

Propuesta:

```js
    function eliminaPares (pareja, elementos) {
      let filtrados = [];
      if (pareja.length != 2) {
        return `El vector ${eliminados} no contiene la pareja de valores requerida`;
      } 
        return filtrados = elementos.filter(numeros => numeros !== pareja[0] && numeros !== pareja[1]);
    }
    
    let numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let eliminados = [2, 3];
    
    console.log(eliminaPares(eliminados, numeros));
```

**Referencias**

- [Método **`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, y pude aprender mucho mas de tu linea de codigo!!

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a SO!

Podrías emplear esta sencilla función para eliminar elementos de dos en dos:

```js
let arr = ['Keep', 'Remove', 'Keep', 'Remove', 'Keep'];

function deleteTwoElements(arr) {
  return arr.filter((el, index) => index % 2 === 0);
}

console.log(deleteTwoElements(arr));
```

Comment: Que no serán retornados, y por tanto eliminados, si ejecutas el código verás el output dado el input que figura en esta respuesta.